# DOM manipulation with querySelector()

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-manipulation, queryselector

I want to pick the `url` value of the `style` in this `div`

```
<div 
class="w-18 h-18 sm:w-20 sm:h-20 bg-gray-200 mx-auto bg-center bg-cover border border-gray-400 rounded-ch" 
style="background-image: URL('https://d14u0p1qkech25.cloudfront.net/club_8702_65d827dd-03b9-4cce-8876-8bd33f306460_thumbnail_250x250')"
></div>
```

I was able to get the `div` with

```
document.querySelector('rounded-ca')
```

Then I used the `.style` property on the `div` to pick the `style` but it's only returning an `object` like this

```
{ "0": "background-image" }
```

How can I then get the `url` value assigned to `background-image`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the `.getAttribute()` property on the picked `document` to get the style attribute like this

```
document.querySelector('rounded-ca').getAttribute('style')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```js
div = document.getElementsByClassName("rounded-ch")[0]
style = div.getAttribute("style")
link = style.replace("URL('", "").slice(0, -2)
console.log(link)
```

```html
<div 
class="w-18 h-18 sm:w-20 sm:h-20 bg-gray-200 mx-auto bg-center bg-cover border border-gray-400 rounded-ch" 
style="background-image: URL('https://d14u0p1qkech25.cloudfront.net/club_8702_65d827dd-03b9-4cce-8876-8bd33f306460_thumbnail_250x250')"
></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `style` property of the div holds properties than you described. You can access each style property, like `background-image`, by accessing it's camelCased property. For example: `style.backgroundImage`.

Then check the string for the content between the `url("` and `")` characters.

```js
const div = document.querySelector('.rounded-ch');
const { backgroundImage } = div.style;
const pattern = /(?<=url\(").*(?="\))/g;
const [url] = backgroundImage.match(pattern);
console.log(url);
```

```html
<div 
class="w-18 h-18 sm:w-20 sm:h-20 bg-gray-200 mx-auto bg-center bg-cover border border-gray-400 rounded-ch" 
style="background-image: URL('https://d14u0p1qkech25.cloudfront.net/club_8702_65d827dd-03b9-4cce-8876-8bd33f306460_thumbnail_250x250')"
></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the documentation for [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle):

```
let element = document.querySelector('rounded-ca');
let compStyles = window.getComputedStyle(element);
console.log(compStyles.getPropertyValue('background-image'));
```